# Log File Sync by Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to Sync Log files from a server to a network share, with an interval of every 5 minutes. Sometimes the Log files size increase to GBs. At that time, copying large files over the network will take much time and bandwidth.

Is there anyway to copy the only modified contents to destination files?

For example the script first copy the all files to destination. Then 2nd time when the script will run after 5 minutes, it will copy the extra contents which get added in last 5 minutes.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for `robocopy.exe`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/181579/need-backup-program-capable-of-copying-delta-incremental-file-changes-only http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple robocopy command will do this for you, you can run it multiple times and it will not copy a file if it has not changed. The basic syntax would be something like this:

```
robocopy "C:\logs" "\\server\share\logs\" /W:2 /R:5
```

The `/W` and `/R` switches set the wait and retry options; in this case, Robocopy will retry each copy up to 5 times, waiting 2 seconds between attempts. (The defaults allow 1 million retries, at 30-second intervals!)

The 'Repeated Copy Options' might also be useful to you:

- `/MON:n` : MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
- `/MOT:m` : MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.

Robocopy is immensely powerful, and has too many options to cover here. To see the full syntax, type `robocopy /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. robocopy is giving the desired result.